Jenkins credentials for SonarQube token won't update
My SonarQube token is expired and I got this message in Jenkins:
INFO: Default locale: "en_US", source code encoding: "windows-1252" (analysis is platform dependent)
INFO: Load global settings
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: Total time: 0.968s
INFO: Final Memory: 5M/56M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error during SonarScanner execution
ERROR: Not authorized. Please check the user token in the property 'sonar.token' or the credentials in the properties 'sonar.login' and 'sonar.password'.

I tried to update it in the credentials by making a new user token in SonarQube under the tab 'Security'. After that I created a new secret text with the token as the credentials. And i updated it in my system config by adding the new key. It is still not working. Did I miss something? It worked before the token expiration and what i could remember I did the same setup.

It was something in my Jenkinsfile. I deleted this line: withSonarQubeEnv('sq1') {
My jenkins could not find the installation place because of this. I re-entered this and now it works.
